# List value gets altered on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-listview, textview

Referring to below screenshot, `ListView` consists of 3 `TextView`.

Depending on the value of 3rd `TextView`, Respective color is assigned to the text of 3rd `TextView`.

i.e. 1.) Green if value>0

2.)Red if value<0

3.) White if value=0 (default)

Following code snippet is used inside an Adapter.

```
if (Float.parseFloat(map.get(RecentChg_COLUMN)) > 0) {
            holder.tvRecentChg.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

else if (Float.parseFloat(map.get(RecentChg_COLUMN)) < 0) {
            holder.tvRecentChg.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

1st screen shows the correct output.

But on orientation change, output comes as shown in 2nd screen.

Lets concentrate on **SHARIABEES**, for which value=0.0

Initially it appears in white, but on orientation change it's color changes to Red.

I have no idea why it might be happening.

Any suggestions welcomed....

[image: screen]

Comment: `Note that if value is >0 or <0, everything works fine. Problem arises when value=0` hmmm, why, oh why .... coz you do not setting color when value is 0 ... and you're not aware of listview optimization even if you're using "holder pattern"(copy paste programming ftw, hehe)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but what do you mean by `listview optimization`. I'm new to android development, so I've no idea about it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html ... simply ... lv is not creating row view for evry row ... lv creates only visible rows + few more and reusing it ... so it is possible that you'll get row that previusly was "red" or "green" and this is why you should also add code for value == 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the else part also for value = 0

```
if (Float.parseFloat(map.get(RecentChg_COLUMN)) > 0) {
        holder.tvRecentChg.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

else if (Float.parseFloat(map.get(RecentChg_COLUMN)) < 0) {
        holder.tvRecentChg.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
else if (Float.parseFloat(map.get(RecentChg_COLUMN)) == 0) {
        holder.tvRecentChg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

and in the androidmanifest.xml file in you  tag set this

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Comment: I had completed the 2nd part from a while but adding that 3rd condition did the trick for me. But **WHY** that has to be done?

Comment: Because views fro individual list entries are reused by android framework. This way you can have fast scrolling lists with a lot of entries ( >1000 ).  But price for this is that you can not assume that list entry you arepopulating rightnow is in default state.